# UIToolbar items disappear - Weird bug in ios6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

This is the current setup.

I have the navigationController's toolbar with 5 buttons, and tapping on them hides the toolbar for 2 seconds, and then shows the toolbar again (except the 5th button - which brings up an actionsheet with buttons (ACTION & CANCEL)).

On tapping on the 1-4 buttons, I do a `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;` and after exactly *2 seconds*, I set the `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;`  and this brings back the toolbar, and everything's fine.

On tapping the 5th button, which brings up action sheet.

1. If i tap on CANCEL actionsheet => actionSheet dismissed => Toolbar is fine.
2. If I tap on ACTION button I do a `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;` and after 2 seconds... `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;`
   but now... The toolbar buttons are GONE.

Further investigating...

I can see the the toolbarButtons seem to have their ***alpha*** values set to 0.

I have no idea why the toolbar items' alpha are set to value = 0 after actionsheet operation.

Can anyone tell me the root cause for this?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried setting the toolbar items array to nil? I had this same problem and it turned out that putting a check around when you set the toolbar's items seemed to work:

```
if ([self.navigationController.toolbar.items count] > 0) {
   [self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:nil];
}

[self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:toolbarItems]; //toolbarItems is your array of UIBarButtonItems.
```

Comment: Does it get into the if statement when you put in breakpoints? This problem was killing me and this is what worked for me...

Comment: Yeah it does get into the IF statement.  I don't think it's right to solve it in this manner. The toolbar does not need to be set again, and again. Setting once should be sufficient.

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I could not find the reason for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue in a different way.  I hide the toolbar when the action sheet comes up, and after the `buttonAction()`, I essentially show the toolbar again.

This solves the problem where the toolbarItems disappear.

But the reason as to why the toolbarItems disappear and set alpha=0 is still a mystery for me. If anyone finds out the reason, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and reproduced it in one of the samples. It appears to be a bug in iOS6 when setting up toolbar items manually in loadView / viewDidLoad, then later calling an ActionSheet.

The code below is a workaround it -

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSArray* items = self.toolbarItems;
    [self setToolbarItems:nil];
    [self setToolbarItems:items animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: My work around was to hide toolbar when actionsheet was up, and show it back after actionsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by moving action code to separate method and then calling it through sending message `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with 0.25f second delay

Example:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(logout) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25f];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the case, I found out that the disappeared items were actually in the toolbar, but placed over the bottom of the view. Maybe resetting them on certain circumstances may cause autolayout issues.

I fixed it by calling the setNeedLayout method on the viewcontroller's view (not the navigationControllers')

```
self.toolbarItems = toolButtons;
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
```