# InputAccessoryView with disappearing buttons

Tags: ios, accessoryview

I have this InputAccessoryView appearing for a textview and it works fine. However if I click the shareButton on the accessoryview and then hit cancel to continue writing, the accessoryview gets empty. It still appears as a toolbar but all the buttons are gone, what am I doing wrong here?

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
[toolbar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(shareIt:)];

UIBarButtonItem *flexButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboard)];

NSArray *itemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:shareButton, flexButton, doneButton, nil];


[toolbar setItems:itemsArray];

[_textView setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];

return YES;
}
```

and this is the method shareIt:

```
- (void)shareIt:(id)sender {
NSArray *activityItems;

activityItems = @[_textView.text];


UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
NSLog(@"buttonCalle");
}
```

Comment: Can you share the shareIt: method please

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226859/uitoolbar-items-disappear-weird-bug-in-ios6